# How to access numpy default global random number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-random

I need to create a class which takes in a random number generator (i.e. a `numpy.random.RandomState` object) as a parameter. In the case this argument is not specified, I would like to assign it to the random generator that numpy uses when we run `numpy.random.<random-method>`. How do I access this global generator? Currently I am doing this by just assigning the module object as the random generator (since they share methods / duck typing). However this causes issues when pickling (unable to pickle module object) and deep-copying. I would like to use the RandomState object behind numpy.random

PS: I'm using python-3.4

Comment: @user2357112 In general I would not expect modules to be picklable, since they can contain all manner of unpicklable objects (C extensions, lambdas, closures etc.)

Comment: @ali_m: I could've sworn they were pickled and unpickled by name, just like functions and classes, but apparently not. When I try it, I get an error too.

Comment: @user2357112 There's nothing *intrinsically* unpicklable about modules. As long as they contain only picklable objects then you're fine, but for most non-trivial modules this isn't the case. For example, numpy is riddled with unpicklable C extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as what kazemakase suggests, we can take advantage of the fact that module-level functions like `numpy.random.random` are really methods of a hidden `numpy.random.RandomState` by pulling the `__self__` directly from one of those methods:

```
numpy_default_rng = numpy.random.random.__self__
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be more future-proof than directly using _rand. Thanks, I didnt know hat there was such a thing as a `__self__` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.random` imports * from `numpy.random.mtrand`, which is an extension module written in Cython. The [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4878) shows that the global state is stored in the variable `_rand`. This variable [is not imported](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) into the `numpy.random` scope but you can get it directly from mtrand.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random.mtrand import _rand as global_randstate

np.random.seed(42)
print(np.random.rand())
# 0.3745401188473625

np.random.RandomState().seed(42)  # Different object, does not influence global state
print(np.random.rand())
# 0.9507143064099162

global_randstate.seed(42)  # this changes the global state
print(np.random.rand())
# 0.3745401188473625
```

Comment: This is what I decided to do when I posted the question, however I was hoping that there was some way I could acheive this without tapping hidden members (for future-proofness). user2357112's method seems to allow that. So I've chosen that as the answer. Thanks for the response nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to access the global state. However, you can use a RandomState object and pass it along. Random distributions are attached to it, so you call them as methods.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

def computation(parameter, rs):
    return parameter*np.sum(rs.uniform(size=5)-0.5)

my_state = np.random.RandomState(seed=3)

print(computation(3, my_state))
```