# Direct way to access Numpy RandomState object

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numpy-random

Is there are more direct way to access the `RandomState` object created on import other than `np.random.<some function>.__self__`? Both `np.random._rand` and `getattr(np.random, "_rand")` raise `AttributeError`. The former works fine but doesn't seem very transparent/Pythonic, though the most transparent might just be creating a separate `RandomState` object. The purpose is passing the `interal_state` variable to a cython function that calls randomkit functions directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access numpy default global random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985484/how-to-access-numpy-default-global-random-number-generator)

Comment: I see, and the second answer on that page gives me the answer I was looking for. And future-proofing is a good argument for .__self__. Thanks.

Comment: As far I know `__self__` and `_rand` are the only way to access the actual global `RandomState` object. Usually it's better (and more pythonic :)) just to create a new instance and use that.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to do, which also makes for easier unit testing if my functions accept Random State objects as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.get_state()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.get_state.html#numpy.random.get_state) to access the random state and [`np.random.set_state()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.set_state.html#numpy.random.set_state) to set it.

Example usage:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> state = np.random.get_state()
>>> np.random.rand()
0.5951085367670415
>>> np.random.set_state(state)
>>> np.random.rand()
0.5951085367670415
```

Note that `state` is just a tuple

```
>>> state
('MT19937', array([3133054952,  999208925, 1226199620, ..., 3991712371,  943990344,
    955790602], dtype=uint32), 624, 0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Then I'd have to (re)create the c level object myself. Why, when it already exists. I suppose my question is why isn't it (more) easily accessible.

Comment: What do you want to do with ti that this does not allow you to do?

Comment: Call a C function (through Cython) that requires a rk_state C type variable (unless I pass the object from Python back to C)

Comment: What C function would require the raw C state?

Comment: Any of the C functions in randomkit, which all require a pointer to a rk_state type. I plan on having multiple threads sharing memory within each process, so I'd like to release the GIL for the major computational work (it's a statistical program).

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it's eventually what I decided to do instead of writing a .pxd file for mtrand. But like I said, I still have to convert it back to rk_state, which by no means trivial and come with define performance blows (3 copies of an array of 624 longs), but it works for me since the numbers only have to be generated once.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer thanks to kazemakase: _rand is accessible directly, I'd just need to import mtrand. But `__self__` may be more future proof, if syntax doesn't change.